# Can we change the a:visited color on the meta.stackoverflow.com home page?

Tags: feature-request, meta, design

When I bring up the meta.stackoverflow.com home page, links I've visited are highlighted with #666666 and the others are highlighted with #3d3d3d. This is hard on my eyes! It's hard to notice the difference. Maybe #666666 could be changed to #999999 or maybe a hint of green? (#9999bb)

I'm guessing I should tag this as a bug... feel free to retag if this is wrong.

Comment: It's a feature AND a bug!

Comment: Okay... can it be fixed?

Comment: How about a red-ish color as used on the navigation bar?