# Difference between link and link:visited on meta is too subtle

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, meta, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we change the a:visited color on the meta.stackoverflow.com home page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42508/can-we-change-the-avisited-color-on-the-meta-stackoverflow-com-home-page)

Earlier today I asked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138815/really-minor-display-issue-in-meta-questions-list) which I thought was a display anomaly.

I quickly learned that this was by design:

```
.question-hyperlink {
  color: #3D3D3D;
}

.question-hyperlink:visited {
  color: #666;
}
```

The problem is, I'm old, and I can only detect these very minor color differences on certain monitors. On most of my devices the color difference is too subtle, to the point where they may as well not be styled differently at all.

I know we seem to like the largely grayscale color theme here, but can we please make some minor adjustments to add some spread between these two styles? I think a very minor increase in spread would differentiate these two links better for everyone (e.g. #2D2D2D and #777).

Comment: Agree, there should be a bigger difference in the colors. It is difficult to tell after a long day of staring at a computer screen.

Comment: @jmort253: You realize that your first link is to this same question?

Comment: @animuson - Hmmm. Nope :) I think I meant to paste this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42508/can-we-change-the-avisited-color-on-the-meta-stackoverflow-com-home-page. Sorry about that. I think it might be time for a break ;)  So... they're either duplicates or closely related, but none of them actually address this issue thoroughly, so I didn't vote to close.

Comment: @jmort253 `1st` link is the same to this question, `2nd` link is about the blue links in the main site, `3rd` is about the old beta sites theme

Comment: @ajax333221 - Absolutely. As I said, the 2nd and 3rd are *related*. As for the mistaken first link, please see the previous comment or just simply click here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42508/can-we-change-the-avisited-color-on-the-meta-stackoverflow-com-home-page.  These are the somewhat related ones from my -- now deleted -- original comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52942/… and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55553/…