# Why does the list of questions not display "accepted" status?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean)

I'm wondering why the question list does not somehow display status of whether an answer has been accepted or not. When Im answering questions, I may choose to skip over those that have already been accepted by the OP.

Is this in the works? Is it something that could be incorporated in a later instantiation of the site?

Comment: The list does indicate this status, it just [isn't always very clear in all cases](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108684/167443)

Comment: @Jim -  
Yes, I am seeing it now, but it is essentially green backing if there are provided answers, the text is white if none are accepted, and yellow if an answer has been accepted. Guess I have only been looking at questions without acceptance already, apologies.

Comment: @Jim yes, agreed. I also filed [this similar issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138815/really-minor-display-issue-in-meta-questions-list) which just demonstrates that the color scheme here on meta is, while intentionally muted, perhaps a little too muted (the differences are so subtle that they are difficult for many users to pick up).

Comment: Actually these are better ones: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138828/difference-between-link-and-linkvisited-on-meta-is-too-subtle & http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42508/can-we-change-the-avisited-color-on-the-meta-stackoverflow-com-home-page

Comment: From doing web work in the past with color blind people, this would be just as difficult for them to pick up as with me (and I obviously didn't pick up on it)!  So thanks for all of the down votes.  This really shouldn't be a differing color within another color box, it should be a similar check mark as within the question itself.

Comment: @trumpetlicks [down-voting is different here on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) than on other sites - it merely expresses disagreement. I didn't down-vote since I happen to agree with you that the color difference is far too subtle on some sites, but I'm sure the down-voters disagree with your assertion that there is no difference - since there is. Perhaps if you word your "question" differently, like a feature request to make it much more obvious that an answer has been accepted, it would receive more favorable response.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Thank you for your suggestion :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The list does display whether there is or isn't an accepted answer.

Questions with an accepted answer have *yellow text* in the "Number of Answers" box.

[image: question accepted]

Comment: FGITW.......... :-)

Comment: Yes, I am seeing it now, but it is essentially green backing if there are provided answers, the text is white if none are accepted, and yellow if an answer has been accepted.  Guess I have only been looking at questions without acceptance already, apologies.

Comment: Is this perhaps too subtle for people with color blindness? @trumpetlicks, do you know or suspect that you have color blindness issues?

Comment: @Mark Ransom - Could be, or maybe its just tiredness from a new baby.  Either way, I think a separate icon indicator from the answer count may be better.  As I said above, perhaps the same green check mark that display with a single accepted question.  Thanks for you understanding!

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Gotta get that coveted "trusted user" somehow ;)