# Increase the visual difference between non-visited and visited links on stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, design, stackexchange.com

On stackexchange.com (not meta.stackexchange.com or other subdomains), non-visited links have the color `#366FB3`, and visited links have the color `#12457C`.

I find the difference very difficult to see- much more difficult to see than on other network sites.

Can the visual difference please be increased?

I was just going through a list of many posts in the network-wide search and it was hard to see which links I had already visited.

Suggestions:

- I think darkening the visited links might make it too dark. The color for visited links seems to already be quite similar to the color of regular text.
- It might be better to lighten and/or increase the saturation for non-visited links (in which case, make sure to make sure that the difference between the color of non-visited link and the color of links that are being mouseovered (`#4CA3D7`) does not become too small (i.e. in this case, also adjust the mouseovered-link color accordingly)).
- As suggested in the comments, just using a different color for visited links also works, and is quite conventional (at least- outside of SE sites).

Note: Here's a related [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), but it's about *meta*.stackexchange.com and not stackexchange.com: [Can we change the a:visited color on the meta.stackoverflow.com home page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42508/997587)

Comment: This. So much this. It is so bad that I simply cannot tell what links I've visited. I've had to resort to a userscript that injects styles to change the color. Another suggestion to add to your list: *decrease* the saturation, making them completely colorless (i.e., gray). Yet another suggestion: make them *purple*, because that's the web standard for links (so much so that [even the official blog makes a pun about it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/06/22/asked-and-answered-the-results-for-the-2022-developer-survey-are-here/), despite Stack Overflow itself not making visited links purple).

Comment: @CodyGray feel free to edit those suggestions into the post and flag my comment here as NLN :)